# Add clients with same name and add it to a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table with the following data:

Table 1:

```
CUSIP DESC QUANTITY

1     ABC    300

1     ABC    400

1     ABC    500
```

I want to move this data into Table 2 but add the quantity if the cusip, and desc are the same

Table 2:

```
CUSIP DESC QUANTITY

1     ABC    1200
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) your columns and `SUM` the QUANTITY:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
   SELECT CUSIP, [DESC], SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY CUSIP, [DESC]
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2620/1/0